# Laravel, Show(), Edit (), update functions not working

Tags: laravel

In the code below methods show, edit update are not working.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\admins;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\contact;
use Image;
use Auth;
use Storage;
use File;

class ContactController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $contact = Contact::orderby('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(5);

        //$agent=Agent::orderby('id','desc')->paginate(5);
        return view('admin.messages.index', ['contacts' => $contact]);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return back()->with('success', 'Message can only be created by Users end.');
    }

    /** * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param \App\contact $contact
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(contact $contact)
    {
        dd(['contact' => $contact]);
        //return back()->with('success','Message Contents Are Already Shown');
    }

    /** 
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource. 
     * 
     * @param \App\contact $contact 
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response 
     */
    public function edit(contact $contact)
    {
        return view('admin.messages.edit', compact('contact'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \App\contact $contact
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, contact $contact)
    {
        dd($request);
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\contact $contact
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(contact $contact)
    {
        return back()->with('success', 'Message history can not be Deleted. ');
    }
}
```

Comment: You're going to have to give a bit more information. What do you expect to happen with the code you have now? You might want to include your controller.

Comment: When you say they're not working, what do you mean? Is there an error? Are they doing something they're not meant to do, or not doing something they are meant to do? Please can you explain the issue in more detail?

Comment: array:1 [▼
  "contact" => contact {#696 ▼
    #guarded: []
    #connection: null
    #table: null
    #primaryKey: "id"
    #keyType: "int"
    +incrementing: true
    #with: []
    #withCount: []
    #perPage: 15
    +exists: false
    +wasRecentlyCreated: false
    #attributes: []
    #original: []
    #changes: []
    #casts: []
    #dates: []
    #dateFormat: null
    #appends: []
    #dispatchesEvents: []
    #observables: []
    #relations: []
    #touches: []
    +timestamps: true
    #hidden: []
    #visible: []
    #fillable: []
  }]

Comment: fetch data from table. But getting blank array,

Comment: write queries first in those functions, ensure there is data in db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using a slug in a route like `contacts/{ slug }`

```php
public function show(contact $contact)
{
    dd(['contact' => $contact]);
    //return back()->with('success','Message Contents Are Already Shown');
}
```

Receives an id not a contact... you are initializing/declaring in the function parameter as contact thats why it somehow gets casted to a contact... but it's an id you should do something like:

```php
public function show($id)
{
    $contact = Contact::findOrFail($id);
    dd(['contact' => $contact]);
    //return back()->with('success','Message Contents Are Already Shown');
}
```

Comment: Solution Worked, Many Thanks @Erubiel !